# facebook comment plugin with angular 8

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to integrate the **facebook comment plugin** with my angular app. I am using the latest version of API. I put

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3"></script>
```

this part of the code inside my index.html.

And put the next part of the code inside a component of a Lazy Module.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-width="" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Now the problem is unless I refresh the comment is not loading. The reason behind that might be the script which has I kept inside downloaded or executed only once and not running everytime I route to my component. How to fix it.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-lazy-load-the-facebook-comments-plugin-using-javascript). Have you tried something like that?

Comment: I tried something like this. As I am using not using vanilla javascript and using typescript and Angular framework it might be a little different. @Dean

Answer (score 0):

The JS SDK goes through your document only once upon initialization; if you add elements to be rendered as social plugins to the DOM later, you need to make it re-parse the document (or a part thereof).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I need to use that comment plugin inside one of my components. Now the first part I kept in a different HTML called index.html. Now where I want to display I kept the last part which another HTML part of another component. Now to use FB.XFBML.parse where should I write the script at index.html or inside the other HTML. I tried to write the code inside index.html. But now when I routed to the new page it is coming but if you back and revisit the same page again that time I can't see it.

Comment: Thank you, brother. I achieved what is needed. Thanks a lot. :)